# Run Google Script on different sheets and documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I think what I'm about to ask has to do with deployments. However, I can't find a clear answer elsewhere.

I created a script that processes timesheet data in a Google spreadsheet, generates a Google document invoice from a template, and then creates email drafts with said invoices attached as PDFs. It all starts with a

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

, which was fine while I was working with a sample spreadsheet of timesheet data. Now, however, I'd like to run my script on a new spreadsheet every month, exported from a time keeping app on my phone. The script is robust enough (and for better or worse, I wrote it in a few different script files to organize my thoughts) that I don't want to have to copy/paste it from file to file every month.

How do I use my script to process a new spreadsheet? I'm having a hard time deciphering the info on deployments and/or missing another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are asking, How do I run a script currently written for the active spreadsheet (the one the script is attached to), on another spreadsheet?

The quickest answer is to replace

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

with

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('{SpreadsheetId}').getSheetByName('{Name of sheet}');
```

where `{SpreadsheetId}` is replaced with the id of the spreadsheet you want to process. That id can be found in the URL for the spreadsheet.  For example, the spreadsheet at the URL
`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19I6BqTKvitlGP_TSKr0wnG7nPvI8VVKw2XSqxTWQjMo/edit#gid=0`

has id `19I6BqTKvitlGP_TSKr0wnG7nPvI8VVKw2XSqxTWQjMo`.

Or you can use

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('{SpreadsheetUrl}').getSheetByName();
```

with the entire URL.

If you are running the script manually, you can manually copy and paste that id/URL into your code each time.  If you need to programmatically discover the file (maybe it's always dropped in the same Drive folder?) that's a more in-depth question.

References:

[`SpreadsheetApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

[`SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)

Comment: Thank you Aaron! I just gave that a try and it does indeed work and will be a perfectly acceptable solution. But it's not ideal: open the script and copy-pasting the id into the script is clunky. I'd love to be in Drive, select a file, and choose a "Make PDF In-Place" option with a right-click or from the menu to save a PDF version of the doc in the same folder. Would that require creating an Add-On or another deployment?